# Arcmap delete feature class after is closed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing

I am facing a strange problem using ArcMap.

Sometimes applying geoprocessing (Buffer,Clip,intersect) or any other tools like "feature to polygon", when I close ArcMap the new feature class is deleted by itself (no matter if it is inside geodatabase or shapefile). It looks like ArcMap delete it automatically.

While ArcMap is open I can do what I want to feature class (copy,export,geoproccesing), i can see the feature class at windows explorer or ArcCatalog but after closing ArcMap it will be deleted and cannot be found even in recycle bin.

This strange problem does not happen everytime, in fact I cannot find or predict when this will happen.

I have tried to replace the arcmap folder "\AppData\Roaming\ESRI", but this doesn't solve the problem.

Does any of you had this kind of problem???

Comment: Are you using a temporary folder to store geoprocessing result data?

Comment: im using permament folder like (C:,D:,Desktop sometimes even default geodatabase).

Comment: The most frequently happens using "feature to polygon" tool

Comment: You may have "Results are temporary by default" enabled. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/using-geoprocessing-options-to-control-tool-execution.htm

Comment: Thanks Luke i saw that and i had temporary checked, perhaps this is what i have been looking for. please write it as answer so i will mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have "[Results are temporary by default](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/using-geoprocessing-options-to-control-tool-execution.htm)" enabled.